# simple way for background task processing in django

Tags: python, django

In my webapp, suppose a user upplaods an image,I want to process that using a script lets say image.py and when its done then add it to dajngo sqlite database.What would be the most straightforward/easy implementation for such task without using celery etc considering processing can take upto 1-2 mins.

Comment: Why aren't you willing to use Celery for this? It's pretty straightforward and widely used.

Comment: actually i am not that experienced. can you provide me a brief roadmap for the following task using celery : user submits an image -> process that image using image.py file -> after processing save it db

Comment: The Celery docs are pretty straightforward. You should just be able to set up the queue worker and your backend of choice (Redis is the simplest), then decorate the function that does the processing and call it using the delay() method.

Answer (score 0):

I think using simple [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) in combination with [cron job](https://coderwall.com/p/k5p6ag/run-django-commands-using-cron) would be pretty easy, since you may not have enough experience to setup the services. Once image is submitted, mark it as `not_processed` and write management command which will use your processing logic and finally it will mark db entry as `processed`.

Answer (score 0):

I have good experience with easy and quick setup of a background task with the django background tasks

http://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

you simply annotate your background task with decorator:

```
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=60)
def your_task():
    pass
```

and then calling this function with schedule the task 60s from now.

easy as that.

Comment: so basically in my view file I've to make a task function and the call it from the view function in which i am getting the response from my form. Am I right?

Comment: yes, basically. although i would put all tasks into separate module called tasks.py to keep it organised in a nice way and to enable easy task discovery.
check docs for details about task discovery

Comment: Not so easy in my case. When I call your_task() within save() it tells me `name 'delayed_work' is not defined`. I wrote the your_task() function to my class in models.py. What do I have to do?